# Passing the value of NR to a variable in AWK

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

Can we pass  `NR` to a variable in `awk` ?

I have a script which goes like this :

```
     awk -v { blah blah..   
     ..........
     count--
     print count
    }
     if (count==0)
    {print "The end of function"
     print NR 
     exit
     }
```

This is the awk part of the code . I want to pass the `NR`  to var2 as :

```
    sed -n ''"$var1"','"$var2"'p'
```

Which has to be reused several times !

Thanks for your replies .

Comment: Why don't you do the substitution inside the awk script?  why do you need sed?

Comment: Yes , but I am not able to define the range using variable in awk :
awk 'NR>="var1"&&NR<="var2"' .

Comment: Yes you can: `NR >= var1 && NR <= var2 {...}`

Comment: @Geekasaur - those quotes make it a literal string, not a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, there are better ways to accomplish the overall goal.

However, in order to answer your specific question:

```
var2=$(awk 'END {print NR}' inputfile)
```

and add anything else you may need within the AWK script.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to print a certain subset of lines you're almost there. The -v flag is the way to go.

```
awk -v var1=15 -v var2=25 'NR>=var1 && NR<=var2 {blah blah ...}'
```

Of course you have to change 15 and 25 to what you need. Observe that variables shoudn't be encapsulated in quotes.

Comment: Passed the bash variables in place of 15 an 25 & it works just as expected...thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you want to achieve with `awk`, `sed` and the `NR` variable. Do you mean the number of lines of the file?

This command gets it:

```
wc -l infile | sed -e 's/ .*$//'
```

So, use it with `-v` switch to `awk` and use it as you want. Next command will print `10` because `infile` has ten lines in my computer.

```
awk -v num_lines=$(wc -l infile | sed -e 's/ .*$//') 'BEGIN { print num_lines }'
```

Comment: I want the exit line of the awk funtion as per the condition. The print NR gives the output to the stdout but cant I pass it to a variable ?